# No counter theorem defined

Tags: newtheorem

I am getting the following error, but cannot figure out the problem yet

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'theorem' defined.
```

I have

```
\newtheorem{galex-theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{galex-corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
```

which could be problematic, but I cannot see it clearly.

Comment: What is the last line suppose to mean? Why is there a `[theorem]` there?

Comment: @daleif: I guess it  means corollaries are numbered per theorem.

Comment: You're naming the environment *and* the counter `galex-theorem`.

Comment: I can do numbering per section with `\newtheorem{galex-theorem}{Theorem}[section]`.  I think one can number per theorem but `[theorem]` is not being recognised.  Perhaps a different keyword should be used for such a thing.

Comment: you could number within `theorem` but first you need to define `theorem`, so far you have only defined `galex-theorem`

Comment: I was under the impression that there exists a theorem counter (`[theorem]`, a variation of it, or some other specific counter) that I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states you have not defined `theorem` however you have defined `galex-thorem` so I assume you intended that. (You give no indication of your intended output)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{galex-theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{galex-corollary}{Corollary}[galex-theorem]

\begin{document}

\section{hmmm}

\begin{galex-theorem}
  $1=0$
\end{galex-theorem}
\begin{galex-corollary}
  everything is provable
\end{galex-corollary}


\begin{galex-theorem}
  a new theorem
\end{galex-theorem}
\begin{galex-corollary}
  corollary 1 (again) as reset by galex-theorem
\end{galex-corollary}
\begin{galex-corollary}
  corollary 2 
\end{galex-corollary}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Correct, I wanted that corollary takes the numbering scheme corresponding to `galex-theorem`.  You got the result I have been working to do.

Comment: Want to ask whether the basic built-in latex has the theorem command with an associated counter.  Or there is just `\newtheorem` where users do construct their own theorem related categorisations?

Comment: you could have just tried \begin{theorem} and seen it is not defined

Comment: You have been of enormous help to me.  I am much more skillful now, and eventually capable of making valuable contributions.